# Intent sent by Alarm PendingIntent has a null Parcelable in the Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to send a bundle through an alarm pending intent, but the parcelable data always seems to be null. The varicable hsr is a Parcelable object.  Here is my code:

```
for (final HolderSubjectReminder hsr : alHolderSubjectReminders) {


  int hours = 23;
  int minutes = 0;
  DateTime alarmDate = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy().plusHours(hours).plusMinutes(minutes);
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.mycompany.ediary");
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putParcelable("Reminder", hsr);
  intent.putExtras(bundle);

  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, count, intent, 0);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

in my BroadcastReceiver (which receives the broadcast at the right time):

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); //not null
        if (bundle != null) {

            HolderSubjectReminder hsr = bundle.getParcelable("Reminder"); //null
            if (hsr != null) {
                subjectReminders.shouldWeShowAlert(hsr);
            }
        }
     }
```

The variable hsr is always null when retrieved in the broadcast receiver.  What am I doing wrong?  The bundle is not null, either, by the way.

Comment: What is hsr? Is it initialized to something?

Comment: @Francesc updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are creating pending intents more than ones in your app. In this case you should use , `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to create the Intent from scratch and inflate your bundle:

Example:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, count, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Flag Info:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT